# Save selected checkbox values to database column

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I need to save string values from multiple check-boxes to a database via an API call. How do I properly model this in my database model such that I can save the string values into one column in my database table. I'm using ASP.NET MVC, I used vue.js on the front-end.

I want to pass an array of strings that represent values from multiple check-boxes to an API endpoint. I represent this as a list of strings in my database model and also want to save the list of string values as a string in my table column.(Note: Not sure if this is a good approach as i'll have to able to retrieve this list later from the database).

```
 public class TempAccountOpeningRequest
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [JsonProperty("first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        [JsonProperty("last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }      

        [JsonProperty("typesSelected")]
        public List<string> TypesSelected { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to be able to pass the values from the multiple checkboxes to an API and then API saves the data to a my data base table

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in one column with comma separate:

Change your Model to:

```
public class TempAccountOpeningRequest
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty("typesSelected")]
    public string TypesSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Your SaveDTO can be like this: (`TypesSelected` will send from vue.js as an array)

```
public class SaveTempAccountOpeningRequestDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<string> TypesSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And your API get data and then convert it to an array and save it in the database:

```
public bool Save(SaveTempAccountOpeningRequestDTO dto)
{
    ...
    string joinedTypesSelected = string.Join(',', dto.TypesSelected);
    ...
}
```

Of course, when you get your data, you should change it to list like this:

```
yourResult.Select(x=>x.TypesSelected.Split(',')).ToList();
```